# What's the best way of sending a string from one computer to the other?

Tags: c#

I have two computers. Neither are on the same network.

Currently, the way I send information is to just make a .txt page on my website and use this code to read from it:

```
//Read top
HttpWebRequest requestTop = HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://MYWEBSITE.com/top.txt");
HttpWebResponse responseTop = (HttpWebResponse)requestTop.GetResponse();
StreamReader readerTop = new StreamReader(responseTop.GetResponseStream());
string resultTop = readerTop.ReadToEnd();
```

The webpage just has the data I want to send on it.

However, this is very time consuming, as I either have to log into FTP (and I don't know that information by heart) or login to the cPanel and go to file manager, navigate to the website, etc...

Is there a way to send data without doing this? The only other option I can think of is to:

1. Create a text file with the string on it
2. Connect to the FTP server with login etc
3. Upload said text file
4. Delete text file from computer.

I could do this however it seems like it probably wouldn't be very efficient. Is there a better way to do it? I'm fine with using my website, but using FTP doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: Is one of the two computers the server or is the server a third computer (that you do not have full control over)?

Comment: A receiving computer I have full control over (UAC, etc). The sending computer is a work computer, so I just have a standard account. The website is on a shared host, but it's on an actual server, not a computer.

Comment: This is kind of fiddly if neither of the computers has a static IP and preferrably hostname. What you're describing is a good chunk of what, say, P2P protocols like BitTorrent do.

Comment: Unless one of the computers is reachable from the Internet (no NAT) and has a static IP or something a dyndns name, both computers need to connect to some server that facilitates the exchange of the data. I would investigate XMPP for this.

Comment: Also: it seems like you could kind of improve on this file exchange approach and use the [Dropbox API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers). You'd basically do the same but bypass the annoying steps of going through your webhost's FTP. Or you could use FTP programmatically but I'm not sure about a C# library for that.

Comment: Honestly the issue here is not that sending text from computer A to computer B is inherently hard, but that making a network connection whatsoever between arbitrarily chosen computers A and B is. Using any sort of public, "well-known" (easily reachable) server is a way to work around this.

Comment: You can send the file via SMTP, and read it via POP3 on the second computer. Email is oldie but still goodie.

Comment: What's wrong with using a form input of type file to upload the file to the website and a link on the website to download the file? Another thought would be using something like signalr.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use web services? asmx or svc works fine in your situation.

Comment: You can have your server A that has the file to expose a web service to read the file, and in server B you can consume the web service.